# mysql to update a database using UPDATE SET and TRIM(LEADING wildcard prefix in record

Tags: mysql, set, sql-update, wildcard, trim

In my database I have a table called 'content' and a field called 'link' and there are almost 300,000 records in that table.

In the field called 'link' there are a number of records that look like this :

http://www.example.com/blah/blah/123456789/url=http://www.destination.com

Unfortunately the prefix part of the records are individually unique where the numbered portion is constant changing from 90 to 150 alpha-numeric characters

I would like to remove the prefix up to and/or including the url=

So that the only thing left in the record is :

http://www.destination.com OR

I could even work with

url=http://www.destination.com
 and simply do a replace command against the "url=" part as a second mysql command.

If there was a wildcard command, this job would be much easier and I would just wildcard everything showing up in the link record between :
http://www.example.com/blah/blah/   wildcard url=
But as everyone knows... there is no such wildcard available

So it had me looking at the UPDATE, SET and TRIM(LEADING commands

UPDATE `content`
SET `link` = 
TRIM(LEADING  'url='  FROM `link`)

But this DID NOT generate the changes I wanted

And so I took the labor intensive method of downloading the database and using a Search and Replace program to make the changes to the 44 thousand records that contained these parameters.

But I would love to find a command that I could simply pass to the database to make this simpler in the future.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this change in the future would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance ;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the part you want to keep always begins with 'http://' you could get the desired result string with the help of the [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```
SELECT CONCAT('http://', SUBSTRING_INDEX(link, 'http://', -1)) FROM content;
```

and fix your table with the simple statement

```
UPDATE 
    content
SET
    link = CONCAT('http://', SUBSTRING_INDEX(link, 'http://', -1));
```

**Explanation:**

SUBSTRING_INDEX with third parameter negative returns the substring from the last occurence of the needle in the second parameter to the end. Because 'http://' isn't included in the return value, we add it again.

Remark:

If you've got https:// urls too, you should be able to adapt my solution.

Comment: It seems to work and nailed thoae prefix parts.  One oddity during its execution is that it didn't seem to distinguish whether the record began with https:// or http://   So if I took the statement and simply substitutes https:// where it has http:// it would then proceed to alter all records to begin with https://    Inversely, if I switched the statement back to http:// it would then proceed to alter all records to begin with http://    BUT other than that bit of an anomaly I THANK YOU. I had been racking my noggin for a couple of hours without anywhere near the success of your code craft ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUBSTRING_INDEX function:

```
UPDATE content SET link=SUBSTRING_INDEX( `link` , 'url=', -1 )
```

I have not tested it, so I would recommend you check that substring_index returns the desired string first.